# can I check if downloaded image is corrupt or not before saving?

Tags: iphone, image, ios4, core-data

can I check if downloaded image is corrupt or not before saving it into my document directory?
if yes then please tell me how?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage *im = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:YourNSData];
UIImageView *imview;

// test to see if the image was successfully created
if (im){
   imview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:im];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: will it return false in the case image is not formed..?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load the `NSData` object in a `UIIImage` with the `initData`. Then check if the return `UIImage` object is `nil`.
This is not full proof methods, but should work.